# cakephp running on nginx accessing plugins

Tags: cakephp

I used cakephp for a couple years now running on Apache.
I am running php 5.3 and cakephp 2.2 
I have installed nginx and have a very simple cakephp model working (few tables using scaffolding) and this works perfectly.

I have just install the debug_kit Plugin under the standard APP/Plugin directory and access a page and the logs show it can't find the files
The access log shows it goes to get /debug_kit/css/debug_toolbar.css and the error stays it can't find app/webroot/debug_kit/js/jquery.js

If I try other simple Plugins Chk in essence it can't find the ChkController however the logs show rewritten data: "/index.php", args: "url=Chk"

It seems to imply that for standard models the rewrite is working but for Plugins when it looks up the file the base dir for the Plugin is not being calculated

Any ideas or samples

Many Thanks

Si

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is related to your rewrite rules. I don't know how your nginx rewrite rules look like but these here are working fine for me using any version of cake 2.x.

```
if (-f $request_filename) { 
    break; 
}
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
    break;
}
```

Comment: I agree it is the rewrite rules and I do have 
 if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
            break;
        }